# Starting in a text field, using Swing

Tags: java, swing, authentication

I made a login dialog with JTextField and JPasswordField. However, right now when the popup shows that the "OK" button is highlighted. I want it to start on the username input box as soon as the popup shows. I've looked at many different methods but none of them seem to work. How might I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723257/how-to-set-focus-on-jtextfield

Comment: By default the first focusable component on the dialog will have focus. I'm sure you don't define the "Ok" button first so you must be doing something strange. Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to call `requestFocusInWindow()` on the JTextField. If you've tried this and it doesn't work, then you'd best show us *how* you've tried this.