# How to automatically focus JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

Right now im making a small commander with a `JTextField` as inputField. How do I automatically focus this when the window opens?

There is nothing else to do than inserting something into the field and pressing Enter at the end.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: [How to Set Focus on JTextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6723257)

Comment: Thank you! I could not find this but it helped. Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextField text = new JTextField();
        frame.add(text);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
                text.requestDefaultFocus();
            }
        });
```