# How can I set a Component focused whenever the JFrame is focused (e.g. by clicking or with Alt+Tab)?

Tags: java

I want to have a JFrame. When it's focused (by clicking on it with the mouse, used with Alt+Tab, or somehow else - like by doing it in the program with it's own methods) a specific Component shall be focused directly.

In my Case it would be the following:
Clicked on JFrame -> JTextField is focused and the user can write in it directly.
Greets, JC

Answer (score 1):

Use a [WindowFocusListener](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Window.html#addWindowFocusListener(java.awt.event.WindowFocusListener)) and [requestFocusInWindow](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow()).

```
myFrame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent event) {
        someTextField.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/6723316/15093679, you can do:

```java
in = new JTextField(40);
f.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowOpened( WindowEvent e ){
        in.requestFocus();
    }
});
```

Where `f` is your JFrame and `in` is your JTextField.

Hope this works.